# Sorting nested list of VO with Comparator

Tags: java, spring, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to sort a nested VO with comparator. I am able to do it with collection sort, but intellij shows a warning we must use comparators. But I could not figure this usage when we have list of object with nest objects.

> Reports Comparators defined as lambda expressions which could be expressed using methods like Comparator.comparing(). Some comparators
>   like (person1, person2) ->
>   person1.getName().compareTo(person2.getName()) could be simplified
>   like this: Comparator.comparing(Person::getName). Also suggests to
>   replace chain comparisons with Comparator.thenComparing(), e.g. int
>   res = o1.first.compareTo(o2.first); if(res == 0) res =
>   o1.second.compareTo(o2.second); if(res == 0) res = o1.third -
>   o2.third; return res; will be replaced with
>   objs.sort(Comparator.comparing((Obj o) -> o.first).thenComparing(o ->
>   o.second).thenComparingInt(o -> o.third));

Here is my class

```
public class SortBaseVO {

public SortBaseVO(String prop1, String prop2, String prop3, String prop4, String sortBaseVO2) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.prop2 = prop2;
    this.prop3 = prop3;
    this.prop4 = prop4;
    this.sortBaseVO2 = sortBaseVO2;
}

private String prop1;

private String prop2;

private String prop3;

private String prop4;

private String sortBaseVO2;

public String getSortBaseVO2() {
    return sortBaseVO2;
}

public void setSortBaseVO2(String sortBaseVO2) {
    this.sortBaseVO2 = sortBaseVO2;
}

public String getProp1() {
    return prop1;
}

public void setProp1(String prop1) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
}

public String getProp2() {
    return prop2;
}

public void setProp2(String prop2) {
    this.prop2 = prop2;
}

public String getProp3() {
    return prop3;
}

public void setProp3(String prop3) {
    this.prop3 = prop3;
}

public String getProp4() {
    return prop4;
}

public void setProp4(String prop4) {
    this.prop4 = prop4;
}
```

}

Class B

```
public class SortBaseVO2 {


    private String a;

    private String b;

    private String c;

    private String d;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

}
```

Current sorting done is sortBaseVOList is a list of sortBaseVO

```
Collections.sort(sortBaseVOList , (sortBaseVO1, sortBaseVO2) ->
        sortBaseVO1.getsortBaseVO2().getB().concat(sortBaseVO1.getsortBaseVO2().getD())
        .compareTo(sortBaseVO2.getsortBaseVO2().getB().concat(sortBaseVO2.getsortBaseVO2().getD()));
```

Can I change this to use Comparator?

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question right. If you don't want to define a comparator in the Collections.sort(), you have to implement Comparable<VO> interface by your VO classes.

Comment: Some types are wrong define in your example. For example, property SortBaseVO#sortBaseVO2 is define as String, but I guest that the type should be SortBaseVO2.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated your problem.

I suggest the following alternative as the right way to fix this warning:

```java
List<SortBaseVO> sortBaseVOList = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(sortBaseVOList , Comparator.comparing(SortBaseVO::getConcat));
```

where in your SortBaseVO class you must to define the following method:

```java
public class SortBaseVO {

    // all other methods

    public String getConcat() {
        return getSortBaseVO2().getB().concat(getSortBaseVO2().getD());
    }
}
```